# Split and reformat strings from array, check if string starts with certain characters, add missing characters, map result to new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of usernames + IDs (IDs start with an `<@`),  that I'd like to perform multiple operations on in the same function.

Namely:

1. Split the strings based on the "|" separator.
2. check if each string starts and ends with `<` and `>` respectively. If not, we will add these back to the string (to restore any missing from a split.)
3. Output the results to two different arrays, `usernames` and `userIDs`

I have the split part working fine, e.g. our current output from the below would be:

```
<@u01d01m666e,banana050>,<@u01bgh5hads,apple060>
```

as `String.startswith()` is unavailable for Arrays, what's the best method to approach this? Should each operation be a separate function, or is it feasible to complete all tasks under one function?

The desired output in this case would be:

a return value of two arrays:

Array #1 contains the UserIDs, in this case:

```
<@u01d01m666e>,<@u01bgh5hads>,
```

Array #2 contains the usernames, in this case:

```
<banana050>,<apple060>
```

```js
var usernames = ['<@u01d01m666e|banana050>', '<@u01bgh5hads|apple060>'];

var userIDs = usernames.map(function mapper(value, index, array) {
  if (typeof value == "string") {
    return value.split("|");

  } else {
    return value.map(mapper);
    console.log("The array mapper was given an incorrect input (not a string.)");
  }
});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userIDs;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1 id="demo"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's how to do it with regular expressions: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/b6ry9j3L/

Comment: @ChrisG If you have a solution post it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar No, I only post answers if the question is a suitable addition to SO; I don't think this one is. This is several basic, already answered questions rolled into one.

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris. I didn't realise I could use the push function in this manner.

I'l make sure to go through the logic and practice it so I have a full understanding of how this works. TYVM!